# ONNX export failed on an operator with unrecognized namespace 'torch_scatter::scatter_max'

Tags: python, onnx, torch-scatter

I have a pytorch network like this

```py
import torch.nn as nn
import torch_scatter.scatter_max

class DGCN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def forward(self, x):
        ...
        torch_scatter.scatter_max(x, index, dim=0)
        ...
```

But when i want export my model to onnx, i face this error:

```bash
  ...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/onnx/utils.py", line 1115, in _model_to_graph
    graph = _optimize_graph(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/onnx/utils.py", line 663, in _optimize_graph
    graph = _C._jit_pass_onnx(graph, operator_export_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/onnx/utils.py", line 1909, in _run_symbolic_function
    raise errors.UnsupportedOperatorError(
torch.onnx.errors.UnsupportedOperatorError: ONNX export failed on an operator with unrecognized namespace 'torch_scatter::scatter_max'. 
If you are trying to export a custom operator, make sure you registered it with the right domain and version.
```

So, How i can do this exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The `Max` reduction attribute for Scatter was recently added in ONNX opset 18 [PR](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/pull/4411).

Unfortunately the pytorch to onnx exporters haven't been updated accordingly.

One approach you could take is to make some changes to the Pytorch repository  in a fork. You could add the following lines to [symbolic_opset18.py](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/onnx/symbolic_opset18.py)

```
from torch.onnx import _type_utils, symbolic_helper
from torch.onnx._internal import _beartype, jit_utils, registration

@_onnx_symbolic("aten::scatter_max")
@symbolic_helper.parse_args("v", "i", "v", "v")
@_beartype.beartype
def scatter_max(g: jit_utils.GraphContext, self, dim, index, src):
    if symbolic_helper.is_caffe2_aten_fallback():
        return g.at("scatter", self, dim, index, src, overload_name="src")


    src_type = _type_utils.JitScalarType.from_value(
        src, _type_utils.JitScalarType.UNDEFINED
    )
    src_sizes = symbolic_helper._get_tensor_sizes(src)
    index_sizes = symbolic_helper._get_tensor_sizes(index)


    if len(src_sizes) != len(index_sizes):
        return symbolic_helper._unimplemented(
            "scatter_max",
            f"`index` ({index_sizes}) should have the same dimensionality as `src` ({src_sizes})",
        )


    # PyTorch only allows index shape <= src shape, so we can only consider
    # taking index as subset size to src, like PyTorch does. When sizes for src
    # and index are not matched or there are dynamic axes, we take index shape to
    # slice src to accommodate.
    if src_sizes != index_sizes or None in index_sizes:
        adjusted_shape = g.op("Shape", index)
        starts = g.op("Constant", value_t=torch.tensor([0] * len(index_sizes)))
        src = g.op("Slice", src, starts, adjusted_shape)


    src = symbolic_helper._maybe_get_scalar(src)
    if symbolic_helper._is_value(src):
        return g.op("ScatterElements", self, index, src, axis_i=dim, reduction_s="max")
    else:
        # Check if scalar "src" has same type as self (PyTorch allows different
        # type for scalar src (but not when src is tensor)). If not, insert Cast node.
        if _type_utils.JitScalarType.from_value(self) != src_type:
            src = g.op(
                "Cast",
                src,
                to_i=_type_utils.JitScalarType.from_value(self).onnx_type(),
            )


        return g.op(
            "ScatterElements",
            self,
            index,
            src,
            axis_i=dim,
            reduction_s="max",
        )
```

Note that this code was just shamelessly taken from [symbolic_opset16.py](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/100641aadfbfe0efe182698e7eb23e02220f0c35/torch/onnx/symbolic_opset16.py#L69-L117), where the export of `scatter_add` is implemented.